Lightleaks since normal maps? Contact shadow option gone?
I was working on a scene, and everything was going great until I decided to add some normals to my materials. Ever since then, I've noticed light leaking near almost every corner. I'm using Eevee, but when I switch to Cycles, the leaks disappear. I really want to get this working properly. Also, I've been searching for the "Contact Shadow" option, thinking that might be the issue, but I can't find it in the usual place anymore. Can anyone help?


The Eevee render engine in Blender 4.2 has been changed & a lot of options have been changed or removed, like Contact Shadows. Have a look here: https://code.blender.org/2024/07/eevee-next-generation-in-blender-4-2-lts/?utm_medium=homepage There is a migration guide linked. (https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.2/eevee_migration/).

Quote from the migration guide: "Contact Shadows is no longer available, since the accuracy of the new shadow maps is enough in most cases. For lights that were set up to rely heavily on Contact Shadows, the Resolution Limit might need to be lowered to avoid light leaking." -- Have you tried that?
